# Android Gridview drag and drop Images and set it to other Imageview

Tags: android, gridview

I have some images in linear layout with"add" icon.I need to set image from GridView below this linear layout.but I have to do this by drag and drop framework.

Thanks in advance

Comment: whats your problem?

Comment: as i I have mention above.

Comment: explain with your code..then only others can identify issue